# Git log for a specific line in a file between the commit id and a prior date?

Tags: git, terminal, git-log, git-blame

Supposing to have a file (and its path) `path/to/file` in a specific version committed in a commit with a specific sha that we call `hex_sha`.
After the use of `git blame file/to/path hex_sha` I get each row modified in that revision.
For this example we assume to check the line with number `line_i`
Supposing to have another prior date `date_limit`.
How can I use `git log` to get how many times (or a list of commits) the line `line_i` in the file `path/to/file` has been modified from the revision with sha `hex_sha` to a specific date `date_limit`?

I tried:
`git log --since=date_limit origin..hex_sha -- -Lline_i,+1:path/to/file` and other different arrangements of this command but nothing happens or git badly understand the file name. I have the impression that after `--` while a target revision is present, git take the first argument after `--` as file path. I'm sure that the date_limit is prior to the commit in exam.

Comment: *Everything* after `--` is considered a path.

Comment: It was my concern, but can I specific other options that require -- (like since)? I'm reading https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log the guide says nothing about my problem

Comment: `--` *by itself*, as in `git something -- whatever`, indicates the end of options. `--option` does not. So `git something --foo --bar -- --baz` means that `--foo` and `--bar` are options to the `git-something` command, but `--baz` is a file name (or pathspec) to the `git-something` command. (Well, there is no `git-something` command, but if there were, that's what these would be.)